# How to update a group of records with incremental values

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I have a table with columns "step_ID", "goal_ID" and "step_number".

step_ID would be the primary, auto-incremented key
goal_ID groups the various steps into specific goals
step_number is currently 0 everywhere, newly created

I want to UPDATE the table so that step_number is set to 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. for every group of similar "goal_ID", ordered by the step_ID.

Said a different way, I'd like to number the steps for a given goal from 0 to however many goals there are, in ascending order of step_ID.

I tried the obvious:

> $query = " UPDATE steps SET step_num = step_num + 1 WHERE goal_ID='689' ORDER BY step_ID";

but that just sets all the rows to 1, (as expected.)

I tried also using various subqueries but I got an error saying I couldn't update a table used in the FROM clause.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update steps
Set step_num =  (
                    Select Count(*)
                    From steps As T1
                    Where T1.goal_ID = steps.goal_ID
                        And T1.step_ID < steps.step_ID
                    )
```

**EDIT**

Looks like you are running into a bug in MySQL with respect to Update queries that contain correlated subqueries. The above would be the standardized version. You can work around the limitation in MySQL like so:

```
Update steps
Set step_num =  (
                    Select Count(*)
                    From    (
                            Select T1.step_Id, T1.goal_Id
                            From steps As T1
                            ) As Z
                    Where Z.goal_Id = steps.goal_ID
                        And Z.step_ID < steps.step_ID
                    )
```

Another solution:

```
Update steps As T1
    Join    (
            Select T1.step_ID, Count(T2.step_ID) As step_num
            From steps As T1
                Left Join steps As T2
                    On T2.goal_ID = T1.goal_ID
                        And T2.step_ID < T1.step_ID
            Group By T1.step_ID
            ) As T3
        On T3.step_ID = T1.step_ID
Set step_num = T2.step_num
```

Comment: I still get error: "You can't specify target table 'steps' for update in FROM clause"?

Comment: @Symmitchry - Looks like you are running into a bug in MySQL. I've posted a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Try break the query into 2, and make use of [mysql user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

like

```
$db->query("SET @counter:=-1");
$db->query(UPDATE steps SET step_num = @counter:=@counter+1 WHERE goal_ID='689' ORDER BY step_ID");
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thanks for the tip. Although I don't know how to extend it to do all goals (i.e. without specifying a goal_ID) I simply repeated the two queries in a FOR loop for all possible goals. Not elegant but quick & easy for a one time update.